# Horizontal extent of tikz picture: Why is it being truncated?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
             axis x line = center,
             axis y line = center,
             xlabel=$x$,
             ylabel=$y$,
             xtick={-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0},
             xticklabels={$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$},
             ytick={-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0},
             yticklabels={$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$},
             domain=-2:2,
             grid=none, 
             unit vector ratio*=1 1,
             enlargelimits = true
            ]
 \foreach \n in {0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3}
  {
   \addplot[
            thick,
            variable=\t, 
            domain=-3:3, 
            samples=200, 
            color=blue
           ] 
            ({\t}, {\t^2/(2*\n^2) - \n^2/2});
 }
 \foreach \m in {0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3}
  {
   \addplot[
            thick,
            variable=\t, 
            domain=-3:3, 
            samples=200, 
            color=red
           ] 
            ({\t}, {\m^2/2 - \t^2/(2*\m^2)});
 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, the picture isn't showing either.  It's here: http://imgur.com/9qIhMkm

Comment: Have you tried `xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5`?

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  Thought I tried it already.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: You might lose the domain as well.

Comment: You may either use `domain=-1:1` or `unit vector ratio*=3 1,`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a simple matter solved in the comments.